# es6 constructor objects passed from source to target file is undefined

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access the object values passed from source file to target file.

Here in the code below, I pass an object named auth from ServiceFile.js to ChildClassFile.js

But outside the ChildClassFile.js the properties inside auth object is undefined. Any help on how to access it would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
// ServiceFile.js

import ChildClass from 'ChildClass';

export default class Service {
  constructor(cookie, token) {
    super();

    this.auth = {
      cookie: 'XXX',
      token: 'XXX',
    };

    this.checkout = new ChildClass(this.auth);
  }

  async serviceMethod(data) {
      return await this.checkout.method1(data);
  };
}

// ChildClassFile.js

class ChildClass {
    constructor(auth) {
      this.auth = auth;
      console.log("ChildClass -> constructor -> this.auth", this.auth); // values are present
    }

    async method1(data) {
        return await axios.post({
            data: data,
            headers: { 
                token: this.auth.token, 
                cookie: this.auth.cookie
            }, // undefined value for both token and cookie
          });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things wrong in your code. You are calling `super` in the Service class but it's not extending any other class.

I've noticed that you're not adding an URL to your POST request.

The following code should work:

```
class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.auth = {
      cookie: 'XXX',
      token: 'XXX'
    };

    this.checkout = new ChildClass(this.auth);
  }

  async serviceMethod(data) {
    return await this.checkout.method1(data);
  }
}

class ChildClass {
  constructor(auth) {
    this.auth = auth;
    console.log('ChildClass -> constructor -> this.auth', this.auth); // values are present
  }

  async method1(data) {
    console.log('ChildClass -> this.auth.token,', this.auth.token); // value is present
    console.log('ChildClass -> this.auth.cookie', this.auth.cookie); // value is present
    return await axios.post('where is the url?', {
      data: data,
      headers: {
        token: this.auth.token,
        cookie: this.auth.cookie
      }
    });
  }
}

new Service()
  .serviceMethod('dummy data')
  .then(res => console.log('res', res))
  .catch(err => console.log('err.message', err.message));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code you sent I am unable to get call the source service. And the auth property is not accessible from the ChildClass method1.

Comment: My bad! I read it the other way around. I've updated my answer.  You need to add an URL to every request.